# This site can’t be reachedlocalhost refused to connect

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to convert this app to docker but I'm getting This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect.. even I tried to use docker-compose
Here's my express.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const portNumber = 3000;
const sourceDir = "dist";
const expressStaticGzip = require("express-static-gzip");
app.use(
  "/",
  expressStaticGzip(sourceDir, {
    enableBrotli: true,
    orderPreference: ["br", "gz"],
    setHeaders: function(res, path) {
      res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=31536000");
    }
  })
);

app.listen(portNumber, "0.0.0.0", () => {
  console.log(`Express web server started: http://0.0.0.0:${portNumber}`);
  console.log(`Serving content from /${sourceDir}/`);
});
```

Here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "xbetwin-client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://asimashfaq.github.io/places-app.github.io",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.22",
    "@types/node": "12.12.3",
    "@types/react": "16.9.11",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.9.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "cypress": "^6.2.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "gh-pages": "^2.1.1",
    "google-map-react": "^1.1.5",
    "grunt": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "jest-enzyme": "^7.1.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "navi": "^0.13.6",
    "nock": "^11.7.0",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
    "query-string": "^6.8.3",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
    "react-navi": "^0.13.6",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3",
    "redux-observable": "^1.2.0",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.3",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.4",
    "tailwindcss": "^1.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "^26.4.4",
    "typescript": "3.6.4",
    "wait-for-expect": "^3.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.45.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.7.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npm run clean-dist && webpack -p --config=configs/webpack/prod.js",
    "clean-dist": "rimraf dist/*",
    "lint": "tslint './src/**/*.ts*' --format stylish --project . --force",
    "start": "npm run start-dev",
    "start-dev": "webpack-dev-server --open --mode development --config=configs/webpack/dev.js",
    "start-prod": " npm-run-all --parallel server build",
    "server": "node express.js",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test && jest  --coverage  --watchAll --config=configs/jest.json",
    "test:watch": "NODE_ENV=test && jest --watch --coverage --config=configs/jest.json",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d dist",
    "cypress:open": "cypress open",
    "cypress": "npm-run-all --parallel --silent  'cypress:open' 'start-dev' "
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.2",
    "@cypress/webpack-preprocessor": "^4.1.0",
    "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
    "@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.5",
    "@types/google-map-react": "^1.1.3",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.146",
    "@types/query-string": "^6.3.0",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.5",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.1",
    "@types/reactstrap": "^8.0.6",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-transform-imports": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "brotli-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.0",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^7.1.1",
    "cypress-wait-until": "^1.6.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.10.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.1",
    "express-static-gzip": "^2.0.5",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.12.16",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.3",
    "tslint": "^5.20.1",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
    "tslint-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dashboard": "^3.2.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.2"
  }
}
```

Here's. dockerfile

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . ./

CMD [ "node", "express.js" ]
```

Here's. docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  place-app:
    container_name: place-app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
      - '/app/node_modules'
    ports:
      - 3001:3000
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

docker build successfully creates, image tagged successfully and container build successfully but when I try to connect on localhost, it says This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect
Help is appreciated.

Comment: What's your host OS?  (Are you using Docker Toolbox on a slightly older Windows?)

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm using Docker Desktop on the latest Windows 10 version